# How to control the vertical distance between the descender and the ascender?

Tags: fontsize, scaling

I want a text to be 0.5 cm tall, that is, the vertical distance between the descender and the ascender should be exactly 0.5 cm. How can I achieve that?

**Edit:** The locations of the ascender, meanline, baseline and descender should be independent of whether the text contains any letter that stretches above the meanline or below the baseline. For example, if the three pieces of text "crane", "aardvark" and "ape" are written separately but on the same row, with no space in between, it should give the same result as if the text "craneaardvarkape" had been written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only a small fragment, the easiest way is to measure the characters and scale suitably. Just some math is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}

\newcommand{\getscale}[1]{%
  {#1*\ratio{\fontcharht\font`l}{\fontcharht\font`l+\fontchardp\font`p}}%
}
\newcommand{\bigfont}[2]{% #1 is the global size, #2 is the text
  \resizebox{!}{\getscale{#1}}{\rule{0pt}{\fontcharht\font`l}#2}%
}

% For testing
\newcommand{\testwithframe}[2]{%
  \sbox{0}{\bigfont{#1}{#2}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-\dp0}{%
    \rule{0.4pt}{#1}\kern-0.4pt
    \rlap{\raisebox{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{0.4pt}}}%
    \rule{\wd0}{0.4pt}%
    \rule{0.4pt}{#1}%
  }}\usebox{0}%
}
\begin{document}

\bigfont{5cm}{Aylip}

\testwithframe{5cm}{Aylip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small overshoot of the ‘A’ and the ‘y’ should not be taken into account. The total height of the frame is exactly 5cm, because it's produced with `\rule{0.4pt}{5cm}` by the testing macro.

Since `\resizebox` considers only the box height, we just have to compute the ratio between the maximum height and the maximum height plus depth of characters, which we multiply the desired size by.

If you instead want to set paragraphs with that font, we need a slightly different computation, which is done by the macro `\fontbydim`:

In the first two lines there's the same example as before. In the third line the font is set with the new command; the first “Aylip” is produced reusing the above box, just for comparison; the second ”Aylip” is typeset in the selected font.

You need a freely scalable font, for this, I used Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\getscale}[1]{%
  {#1*\ratio{\fontcharht\font`l}{\fontcharht\font`l+\fontchardp\font`p}}%
}

\newcommand{\bigfont}[2]{% #1 is the global size, #2 is the text
  \resizebox{!}{\getscale{#1}}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\fontbydim}[1]{%
  \setlength{\dimen0}{10pt*\ratio{#1}{\fontcharht\font`l+\fontchardp\font`p}}%
  \fontsize{\dimen0}{1.2\dimen0}\selectfont
}

% For testing
\newcommand{\testwithframe}[2]{%
  \sbox{0}{\bigfont{#1}{#2}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-\dp0}{%
    \rule{0.4pt}{#1}\kern-0.4pt
    \rlap{\raisebox{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{0.4pt}}}%
    \rule{\wd0}{0.4pt}%
    \rule{0.4pt}{#1}%
  }}\usebox{0}%
}
\begin{document}

\bigfont{0.5cm}{Aylip}

\testwithframe{0.5cm}{Aylip}

\bigskip

\fontbydim{0.5cm}\usebox{0}Aylip

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This actually creates an incorrect result on my computer. As a test, I printed the text `lql` with 5 cm height, but when I measure it on the paper it is 4.6 cm tall. By the way, what does `\ratio{\fontcharht\font\`l}{\fontcharht\font\`l+\fontchardp\font\`p}` do?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Your printer is reducing output, which frequently happens when Adobe Reader is used for printing. The vertical rule in my example is *requested* to be 5cm long, so if it's not that long, printing is not faithful.

Comment: Ah... It was completely Adobe Reader's fault. I had to change the size option from "Shrink oversized pages" to "Actual size". I thought the default LaTeX paper size for the article and report document classes was A4 (I got the same size-down in both cases).

Comment: By the way, I have updated my question. Sorry for doing it now but there was a detail I forgot to mention. :P

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Adobe Reader has the funny belief that A4 paper doesn't fit in A4 paper, so it seizes the initiative and reduces it by 8%. I can't understand the addition, sorry.

Comment: Well, the rectangle did get 5 cm tall after I had changed the size option. However, when writing only `y` or `p`, the result looks slightly funny, since the letter stretches significantly higher than the rectangle, which it doesn't when the text also contains some "tall" letter.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Yes, you're right; I'll fix it. I forgot to set the box height to the height of the ascenders.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't mention the length of text, the easiest is to scale the content using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

\bigskip

\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\end{document}
```

Note that the scaling of fonts in this way is based on the bounding box of each letter. That is, the measurement from the lowest descender to the highest ascender bounding-box-wise will be 0.5cm.

Comment: This could have worked, but unfortunately, I have three texts on the same row, which are left-aligned, centered and right-aligned, respectively, and I suspect that it will be difficult to make sure the font height are the same for all of those, since you would basically need to have one `resizebox` per text.

Comment: This creates an incorrect result on my computer. As a test, I printed the text `lql` with 5 cm height, but when I measure it on the paper it is 5.9 cm tall.

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: I don't know how that could be (I haven't printed it though, but 5cm is 5cm in my book).

Comment: You and egreg have very similar methods. In egreg's method, the size is rescaled with the ratio between the distance between the baseline and the ascender and the distance between the descender and the ascender. Now, I don't know exactly what `resizebox` does, because CTAN seems to be down for the moment so I can't get the documentation for the graphicx package. Anyway, I tried printing the text `lql` with the height 5 cm with both your methods. With your method, the distance between the descender and the ascender becomes 6.4 cm. With egreg's method, it becomes 5.0 cm.

Comment: With your method, however, the `l`s become exactly 5 cm tall.